Terraform Provider display
I'm currently going through the terraform tutorial from hashicorp. I have a K8S cluster to which I access from my machine (~/.kube/config).
I tried to create a small tf file with
provider "kubernetes" {}
terraform apply I get this error
terraform-provider-kubernetes
terraform apply
Error when posting
`terraform apply``

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
